# Setting pivot cache for two subs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this in both of my subs:

```vb
   Set BuforTP = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches. _
        Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Worksheets("Baza").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
```

This in one sub:

```vb
Set TP = Worksheets("Arkusz techniczny").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=BuforTP, _
      TableDestination:=Worksheets("Arkusz techniczny").Cells(1, K), TableName:="TP" & Nr)
```

And this in second:

```vb
Set TP = Worksheets("Arkusz techniczny").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=BuforTP, _
      TableDestination:=Worksheets("Arkusz techniczny").Cells(1, L + 3), TableName:="TPR" & Nr)
```

My problem is that I can't add one slicer to both of this pivot tables and I suppose that's because I set BuforTP twice. I wonder why my pivot tables have "different" data even though it's the same data and how to set variable properly.

I tried to dim public variable or write a function but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: `I can't add one slicer to both of this pivot tables` what's your code to add the slicer? Is there any error?

Comment: Maybe I misplained my problem, sorry. The problem is not adding the slicer but after I create it for pivot table from one sub, I can't connect it to the other from second sub. I've tested this manually in Excel not in VBA but on pivot tables created by the code above.

Comment: Ok, my solution might be just it: 'Worksheets("Arkusz techniczny").PivotTables("TP6").CacheIndex = Worksheets("Arkusz techniczny").PivotTables("TPR1").CacheIndex' which changes pivot cache in table from first sub for pivot cache from table in second sub